# Not able to extend Mage_Cms_IndexController in my custom module, Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to extend `Mage_Cms_IndexController` controller but nothing is happening. My code is under `app/code/local/Ash/Test`  .

code of `app/code/local/Ash/Test/etc/config.xml`

```
 <frontend>
    <routers>
        <ash_test>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Ash_Test</module>
                <frontName>ash_test</frontName>                 
            </args>
        </ash_test>
        <cms>
            <args>                    
                <modules>
                    <Ash_Test before="Mage_Cms">
                        Ash_Test_Frontend_Cms
                    </Ash_Test>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </cms>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

And controller location in my module is

```
app/code/local/Ash/Test/controllers/Frontend/Cms/IndexController
```

and code is

```
 require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Cms').DS.'IndexController.php';
class Ash_Test_Frontend_Cms_IndexController extends Mage_Cms_IndexController
{

public function indexAction($coreRoute = null)
    {
        echo __FILE__;

    }
}
```

I`m not getting what is wrong in it. Please help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things:

### Unwanted space in controller rewrite configuration.

This part is wrong:

```
    <cms>
        <args>                    
            <modules>
                <Ash_Test before="Mage_Cms">
                    Ash_Test_Frontend_Cms
                </Ash_Test>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </cms>
```

Instead, it should look like this:

```
    <cms>
        <args>                    
            <modules>
                <Ash_Test before="Mage_Cms">Ash_Test_Frontend_Cms</Ash_Test>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </cms>
```

Also make sure `<config>` node is present. i.e. your `config.xml` file should somewhat look like this:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ash_Test>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Ash_Test>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <ash_test>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ash_Test</module>
                    <frontName>ash_test</frontName>                 
                </args>
            </ash_test>
            <cms>
                <args>                    
                    <modules>
                        <ash_test before="Mage_Cms">Ash_Test_Frontend_Cms</ash_test>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </cms>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

### Make sure activation file of your extension exists

Make sure following file exists:

FIle : `app/etc/modules/Ash_Test.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ash_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Cms/>
            </depends>
        </Ash_Test>
    </modules>
</config>
```

It is a good practice to make your module depend upon `Mage_Cms` in this case. This will force to load `Mage_Cms` module before yours.

### Make sure php open tag is present in your controller.

you should ensure `<?php` tag is present in your controller. i.e.

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Cms').DS.'IndexController.php';
class Ash_Test_Frontend_Cms_IndexController extends Mage_Cms_IndexController
{

    public function indexAction($coreRoute = null)
    {
        echo __FILE__;die();

    }
}
```

Comment: <depends><Mage_Cms/></depends> is not compulsory here as I did not use it. Is there any other reason ?

Comment: its not compulsory. but it is  good ptactice to include it. it makes your module depends on Mage_Cms and thus that module will load first.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

in config.xml change the `cms` node to this

```
   <cms>
        <args>                    
            <modules>
                <Ash_Test before="Mage_Cms">Ash_Test</Ash_Test>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </cms>
```

Then put your controller in `app/code/local/Ash/Test/controllers/IndexController.php`

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Cms').DS.'IndexController.php';
class Ash_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Cms_IndexController
{

    public function indexAction($coreRoute = null)
    {
        echo __FILE__;

    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is no problem in using `Ash_Test_Frontend_Cms` in this case. This is because he defined the controller in `controllers/Ash/Test/Frontend/Cms`. Problem reside here is, he has unwanted spaces in that declaration (in config.xml). I just tested his configuration in my local machine and it worked :-)

Comment: ^^ I learned above point from "Grokking Magento". Kudos to Vinai :-)

Comment: @RajeevKTomy. I think there is a problem with using it like that `Ash_Test_Frontend_Cms` but not sure. There controller matching behaves strange. I think it allows only 3 elements separated by '_'. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @marus : hm... may be i am wrong. but in this case it worked. Because i just tested his code and i get the file path.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy. Ok. I trust you :)